# Getting different API responses for same request

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to store historical prices for some cryptos from Bitso API.
It looks like every time I run the code, different symbols show up. Meaning, sometimes some symbols have data and some others don't, hence they are printed, showing no consistency. Any idea/suggestion?

Given list:

> base_assets = ['aave_usd',  'ada_usd',  'algo_usd',  'ape_usd',  'ars_usd',
> 'atom_usd',  'avax_usd',  'axs_usd',  'bal_usd',  'bat_usd',
> 'bch_usd',  'brl_usd',  'btc_usd',  'btsoeur_usd',  'chz_usd',
> 'comp_usd',  'cop_usd',  'crv_usd',  'dai_usd',  'doge_usd',
> 'dot_usd',  'dydx_usd',  'enj_usd',  'eth_usd',  'eur_usd',
> 'fcbar_usd',  'ftm_usd',  'galag_usd',  'galat_usd',  'gnt_usd',
> 'grt_usd',  'ldo_usd',  'link_usd',  'lrc_usd',  'ltc_usd',
> 'mana_usd',  'matic_usd',  'mkr_usd',  'mxn_usd',  'near_usd',
> 'omg_usd',  'paxg_usd',  'pepe_usd',  'psg_usd',  'qnt_usd',
> 'sand_usd',  'shib_usd',  'snx_usd',  'sol_usd',  'steth_usd',
> 'sushi_usd',  'tigres_usd',  'trx_usd',  'tusd_usd',  'uni_usd',
> 'usd_usd',  'usdc_usd',  'usdt_usd',  'xlm_usd',  'xrp_usd',
> 'yfi_usd']

My code:

```
import requests
import json
import time
import pandas as pd 

endpoint = 'https://api.bitso.com/v3/ohlc/?book='  # https://github.com/kalinbas/bitso-historical-data

prices_df = pd.DataFrame()

for symbol in base_assets:
    params = {'book': symbol,
             'time_bucket': 86400}

    response = requests.get(endpoint, params=params) 
    result = json.loads(response.text)
    
    try:
        data = result['payload']

        # Create a DataFrame from the data
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

        # Convert timestamps to readable format in the DataFrame
        temp_df['bucket_start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_df['bucket_start_time'], unit='ms')
        temp_df['first_trade_time'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_df['first_trade_time'], unit='ms')
        temp_df['last_trade_time'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_df['last_trade_time'], unit='ms')
        temp_df['symbol'] = symbol
        prices_df = prices_df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)
    except:
        print(symbol)
```

Comment: You'd have to ask the operator of the API why they're inconsistent. This isn't a programming issue.

Comment: How do you know? Perhaps it's a matter of extracting in chunks @Barmar

Comment: If the results are chunked, you need to read all the chunks. Although I'd expect the first chunk to be the same each time. Is the API dependent on the time you call it?

Comment: The parameter `time_bucket` susggests that this is time-dependent, so you get different results at different times.

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of testing and found out that these 16 values are consistently getting skipped from the loop. So I went ahead to manually check these values in the API URL and found out that no data exists for these values.

```
{'fcbar_usd', 'steth_usd', 'eur_usd', 'usd_usd', 'galat_usd', 'galag_usd', 'dai_usd', 'btsoeur_usd', 'usdc_usd', 'cop_usd', 'usdt_usd', 'ars_usd', 'tusd_usd', 'gnt_usd', 'mxn_usd', 'brl_usd'}

i.e fcbar_usd

https://api.bitso.com/v3/ohlc/?book=fcbar_usd&time_bucket=86400
```

returning the response:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "code": "0301",
        "message": "Unknown order book fcbar_usd"
    } }
```

[API response for fcbar_usd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwKkF.png)

Maybe try removing these elements from your list and try again and then catch the ones that are getting skipped again?

```
import requests
import json
import time
import pandas as pd

endpoint = 'https://api.bitso.com/v3/ohlc/?book='  # https://github.com/kalinbas/bitso-historical-data

cleaned_base_assets = ['aave_usd', 'ada_usd', 'algo_usd', 'ape_usd', 'atom_usd', 'avax_usd', 'axs_usd', 'bal_usd', 'bat_usd', 'bch_usd', 'btc_usd', 'chz_usd', 'comp_usd', 'crv_usd', 'doge_usd', 'dot_usd', 'dydx_usd', 'enj_usd', 'eth_usd', 'ftm_usd', 'grt_usd', 'ldo_usd', 'link_usd', 'lrc_usd', 'ltc_usd', 'mana_usd', 'matic_usd', 'mkr_usd', 'near_usd', 'omg_usd', 'paxg_usd', 'pepe_usd', 'psg_usd', 'qnt_usd', 'sand_usd', 'shib_usd', 'snx_usd', 'sol_usd', 'sushi_usd', 'tigres_usd', 'trx_usd', 'uni_usd', 'xlm_usd', 'xrp_usd', 'yfi_usd']

missing = []
prices_df = pd.DataFrame()

for symbol in base_assets:
    params = {'book': symbol,
              'time_bucket': 86400}

    response = requests.get(endpoint, params=params)
    result = json.loads(response.text)
    try:
        data = result['payload']
        print("I am in")

        # Create a DataFrame from the data
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        print("I am here")
        # Convert timestamps to readable format in the DataFrame
        temp_df['bucket_start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_df['bucket_start_time'], unit='ms')
        temp_df['first_trade_time'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_df['first_trade_time'], unit='ms')
        temp_df['last_trade_time'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_df['last_trade_time'], unit='ms')
        temp_df['symbol'] = symbol
        temp_df.to_csv("downloaded_data6", index=False)
    except:
        print(symbol)
        missing.append(symbol)
print(missing)
```

Comment: Wierd, I made no major changes in your code. Maybe you rerun it. It's working fine for me.

Comment: I removed my reply because it seems my IP got banned 24 hrs for making many requests as part of testing. So I will be trying this out tomorrow. I think this might've been the whole issue =/

Comment: Sure, feel free to let me know how it turns out. This API behavior is pretty interesting, happy to dig further.